# Validate controls on conditions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Im struggling getting this to work the way i need. I have two RequiredFieldValidators and two textboxes (Side note: although i have Javascript below i dont mind doing this in another way. I did try code behind but realised validation didnt kick in until i clicked a button twice):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailR" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email" ControlToValidate="EmailTextbox" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="NameTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameR" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter your name" ControlToValidate="NameTextbox" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I then have some script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=EmailTextbox.ClientID%>').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= NameR.ClientID%>'), true);

                }
                else
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= NameR.ClientID%>'), false);

            });
    });
</script>
```

What im trying to do is:

If EmailTextbox has an email then disable NameTextbox validation.
If EmailTextbox has NO email then enable NameTextbox validation and disable EmailTextbox validation.

With me being pretty new to JQuery/Javascript i have tried several attempts in trying to achieve the above however reading more into it, theres a possibility that i could have the wrong JQuery file (that said with this being an existing project i havent really added any ref to any JQuery so it could well be that i have the code right but need a ref to a JQuery or need to include a new version).

Overall if i can

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=EmailTextBox.ClientID%>').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != null && $(this).val().length != 0) {
                $('#<%= NameRequiredFieldValidator.ClientID%>').hide();

            }
            else {
                $('#<%= NameRequiredFieldValidator.ClientID%>').show();
                $('#<%= EmailRequiredFieldValidator.ClientID%>').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you make the validation enable wrongly when a email 
value was not null disable validation on name and enable for email else viceversa

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=EmailTextbox.ClientID%>').keyup(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length)
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= NameR.ClientID%>'), false);
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= EmailTextbox.ClientID%>'), true);

                }
                else
               {
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= NameR.ClientID%>'), true);
                    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= EmailTextbox.ClientID%>'), false);
               }

            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, similar to what you had.

```
function doSomething()
{
  var myVal = document.getElementById('myValidatorClientID');
  ValidatorEnable(myVal, false); 
}
```

Or, you could use the visible=true/false on them which renders them inactive (meaning set visible property from code behind).. This might cost you an ajax trip to the code behind using scripmanager and __doPostBack in order to call a server-side function that can than process your logic... A lot of developers don't realize that at least in webforms, you can call your code behind methods from JS, just be very careful - as each call back can get costly...

A good article on communicating from ("front end to code behind via JS")   - 
 [http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack()_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx)

Hope that helps or get's you back on the right track!!!